# Openerp show message dialog

Tags: odoo

How can I show a message box in openerp? I was using raise like this:

```
raise osv.except_osv(_("Warning!"), _("Error"))
```

But this stops executing other code, I only want to display an informative message box.

Comment: You need to rely on wizard to popup warning, if you don't want to break the code.

Answer (score 2):

Raising an `osv.except_osv` does a couple of things:

1) Interrupts the current processing (it is a python exception after all).

2) Causes OpenERP to roll back the current database transaction.

3) Causes OpenERP to display a dialog box to the user rather than dumping a stack trace and giving the user a "bad stuff happened" message.

For onchange we can return

```
warning = {
        'title': 'Warning!',
        'message' : 'Your message.'
    }
return {'warning': warning}
```

But it will not work for other things like button.

For your case you can do

```
cr.commit()  
raise osv.except_osv(_("Warning!"), _("Error"))
```

But calling `cr.commit` explicitly in business transaction will leads to severe issues.

The other way is you can return a wizard with warning message. This is what most people used.

```
return {
            'name': 'Provide your popup window name',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': [res and res[1] or False],
            'res_model': 'your.popup.model.name',
            'context': "{}",
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'nodestroy': True,
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': record_id  or False,##please replace record_id and provide the id of the record to be opened 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way comes to my mind... You can use some `on_change` method that would return dict like this:

```
return {
        'warning': {
              'title':'Message title!',
              'message':'Your message text goes here!'
               }
        }
```

Comment: This requires to user to actually change something, I could also trigger it using _constraint but this also requires something to change. I need it to show the message just by opening a customer for example.

Comment: Then I suggest you  add some dummy field (boolean or char) to your model (for example, let's call it "show_message"). Add that field to _defaults = {'show_message': True} and bind on_change method to that field. That way, when user opens your form view, on_change method will run, and show your message.

Comment: That will not work cause on_change requires the user to change that specific field. Manipulating it code-wise will not trigger the on_change

Comment: Do you need this for regular osv.osv model or wizard?

Comment: For a regular osv.Model

Comment: I think that "no coder" has given you the right answer (last code block, where you return wizard form containing message). In my scenario, on_change method will be invoked on Create button, but not if user opens form view of existing record...